# How to connect a ZKTeco device with laravel which is protected by Communication Password

Tags: laravel, integration, zkteco

I am facing an issue that my client have an attendance device ZKTeco K50 which is protected by communication password. Using rats/zkteco when I send request for connecting with device it connects but after that I am unable to get data from device and send data to device due to communication password protection.

I checked in package but there is no way to send communication password and also tried to alter the package but it did nothing.

Please answer if anyone know anything.

Answer (score 0):

@KGG is correct. I will offer a few hints to get you started:

1. this is the best description of the ZKTeco protocol that I have found: https://github.com/adrobinoga/zk-protocol . Reading it is a good idea.
2. you will want to research the CMD_CONNECT message. When sending it gets a CMD_ACK_UNAUTH message in response, you need to fetch the comm key and compute the crazy ZKTeco secret
3. You send a CMD_AUTH message to the clock inserting the magical number computed in point 2. If it is good you will get a CMD_ACK_OK message
4. you will find a python library from the author of the protocol spec here: https://github.com/adrobinoga/pyzatt that looks pretty good to my eyes though I don't do python
5. And here https://github.com/fananimi/pyzk you will find the function make_comm_key which should get you started

Answer (score 0):

You have to check if your server provider gives you access to the Firewall
in my case I manage WHM where I configure IP and port

[image]

[image]